# Mvc.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationFilter - System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'UserManagerProxy'

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

My controller is like this and I am getting  Cannot access a disposed object

[AbpMvcAuthorize(AppPermissions.Pages_Administration_FSUsers)]
    public class FendleyStaffController : FSControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserAppService _userAppService;
....}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDx6I.png)

Comment: Welcome stackoverflow. Please don't use images for logs you can copy here. Also, please paste the code lines where you got the error. That will help a lot for trying to help you.

Comment: This is the log